# get PID of PHP file executed with shell_exec with continuous output

Tags: php, shell-exec

I do have a PHP script which has a continuous ouptput (written to tmp file for logging). So far, I started the script right from the shell, but now, I would like to start it via shell_exec:

```
shell_exec("file.php >> /path/to/log 2>&1 &");
```

But shell_exec always return null instead of the PID. 
How can I get the PHP process ID and keep the output written to the file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Look into `proc_open` and `proc_get_status` instead.